# How do I create an animation of scrolling text with just HTML and CSS (or java i guess) like apple used to have on their livepage?

Tags: html, css, animation, canvas

I have a banner at the top of my website that is blue with a light radial gradient on the left side.

I want to have white text animated that scrolls up on the right side of the banner.  I want it to fade in as it appears and then fade back out.  I would like to do this without the use of Flash, and as little Java as possible.  I can work my way through CSS and set up the layout, but I don't know how to code it so that the animation will work.

I'd also like the white text will be the titles and a very brief summary of recent blog posts for the site.  (probably the RSS summary)  I don't know if that's easy to code into it or if I'll need to hand code that every time I have a new blog post.

After some basic research I think what I'm looking for is HTML 5 canvas, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Update: 10/21/2015: The following answer required you to explicitly provide values such as 100em in order to achieve offsets. This is not ideal. Instead, [you can translate the element](http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/yxppkv3j/).*

**Update**

You can indeed do this *today* without flash or JavaScript. You can use the `keyframes` feature in modern browsers to move text in modern browsers. I took the liberty to work up a quick demo demonstrating the concept: (horizontal) http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/XxUXD/, and (vertical) http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/h7SYp/.

Essentially we set the initial starting-point of the animation to `text-indent: 100%` to set it out of view and to the right. Then we set the last frame to `text-indent: -100%`, or whatever is needed to hide the text (will vary depending on character-length).

**Old Answer**

You won't be able to do this without flash or Javascript. HTML is structure, while CSS is presentation. Neither of the two provide animation-capabilities. I would suggest you go a route that includes a small javascript framework like jQuery, as this can convert standard HTML into the animated effect that you desire.

I would encourage you to look into the [Cycle Plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/) for jQuery.

Comment: this one doesn't seem to work with just raw text, or am I missing something?

Comment: @JonathanSampson with chromium v. 22 and midori v. 0.4.3 on raspberry with raspbian

Comment: The latest version (translating the element) gets faster the longer the text you put in it...

Answer (score 3):

What you need is JavaScript rather than flash or java.

[JQuery](http://www.jquery.com) is ideal for this type of animation.  It's a JavaScript library that simplifies writing such JavaScript functions. There are many plug-ins available for jQuery that give similar functionality to what you require - have a look at [JQuery Marquee](http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html)

Comment: Agreed.  Don't be intimidated by jQuery as a novice web developer either, it's very easy to use.

Comment: does javascript run on the iphone?

Comment: Yes Safari on the iPhone handles JavaScript fine

Answer (score 0):

You'll certainly need to use JavaScript, unless you want to use Flash. You cannot do it without a program.

Your best bet is to look into an animation library.

[Scriptaculous](http://script.aculo.us/) can do everything you describe, but doing what you describe is not for a JavaScript beginner.