# How do I have text that scrolls upwards?

Tags: javascript, html

The most common answer across the internet is to use a Marquee, but I was told that it is outdated and has problems. But I went with it anyway and now I can't get it to work, which begs the question, how do I have text scrolling upwards in a sure shot method that works properly? The code I have right now works sometimes, sometimes it doesn't work. It also takes too long to scroll back up into visibility.

My other requirement is that if the line of text is just one line, then don't scroll. How can I make this happen?

This is what I have so far:

```
<div class="message_div" style="height:1em; left: 136px; bottom:0px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; background: white; box-sizing: border-box;">
  <span class="message">{% for message in product|product_message:request.user %} {{message.message|safe}} {% endfor %}</span>
</div>

<script>
function message_function()
{
    var th = $(this);
    var ih = $(this).outerHeight(); // outer height
    var oh = $(this).find('.message').outerHeight(); // inner height
    var txt = $(this).find('.message').html(); // so that the inline styles remains the same
    if (oh > ih)
    {
        th.html('');
        th.html('<marquee class="message" direction="up" scrollamount="1" scrolldelay="0" onmouseover="this.stop()" onmouseout="this.start()">' + txt + '</marquee>')
    }
}

($('.message_div').each(message_function));

</script>
```

Comment: _But I went with it anyway_ ............................

Comment: Like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/hmPPe/5/

Comment: @baao Sad life of a programmer :(

Comment: Not at all, you're not a programmer if you do such stuff

Comment: @baao Well ok, sad life of a bad programmer

Comment: Not even a bad programmer :D A guy who takes code from the internet to make it his own maybe... :P

Comment: @baao I was going to say sad life of a programmer, but then you'd say not even a programmer. So I'll just say sad life.

Comment: Now I feel with you :D

Comment: @Korgrue Your fiddle is close, but if I have just have a single <p></p> tag is appears twice

Comment: So... You're asking us to get the `marquee` tag working for you, even though you've been told that you should not use it because it doesn't work any more?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan No! Not at all. I'm asking for an alternative to marquee to get scrolling text

Comment: Well, there are plenty of resources on the internet which show how to do this. In fact, even on this site. http://stackoverflow.com/q/2136030/215552 for instance.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan The answer to that question is still using a marquee though

Comment: First of all, there are three answers on that question. Secondly, the accepted answer is certainly not using a marquee element. Please do read the answer, and click through to the jsfiddles attached.

Comment: Updated my solution to only use a single pair of <p> tags. See the full answer below.

Answer (score -1):

Here:

http://jsfiddle.net/hmPPe/338/

I adjusted it so that it only uses a single paragraph.

**JS**

```
(function($){

    $.fn.rollup = function ( options ) {

        var settings = $.extend( {
            $wrapper : this,
            $content : $('.scrolling-div-content'),
            speed : 5000
        }, options);

        return this.each( function(){

            var $content = settings.$content,
                $content_height = $content.height(),
                $wrapper = settings.$wrapper,
                $wrapper_height = $wrapper.height(),
                $clone = $content.clone(),
                $merge = $.merge( $content, $clone );

            $wrapper.append( $clone );

            function rollUp () {
                $merge.animate({
                    top : -( $content_height ),
                }, settings.speed, 'linear', function () {
                    $merge.css({
                        top : 0
                    });
                    rollUp();
                });
        }

        rollUp();

        });
    };
})(jQuery)

$('.scrolling-div').rollup({speed:2000});
```

**HTML**

```
  <div class="scrolling-div">
  <div class="scrolling-div-content">
    <p>
      1<br>
      1<br>
      1<br>
      1<br>
      1<br>
      1<br>
      1<br>
    </p>
    </div>
<div>
```

**CSS**

```
.scrolling-div{
  height:100px;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid #333;
}
.scrolling-div-content{
  position:relative;
}
```